# March 2013: Paypal Sandbox login loops back to developer page

Tags: authentication, paypal, sandbox

Since Paypal developer changed in March 2013, I've been unable to get into the sandbox.

I logged in to the new developer site OK with my actual Paypal account details.

I managed to import my accounts into the new development site (marked worryingly as 'beta') using the link
**"Looking for Sandbox? Import your test accounts to continue testing. Learn what's new."**

But clicking the link 'Sandbox site' on any of the accounts results in me being taken to:

[This is the link](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_home&country_lang.x=true) where I'm greeted with a Paypal Sandbox logo and a single link reading "Please log in to use the PayPal Sandbox features."

Clicking on this link takes you back to where you have come from - that is the developer page where I am already logged in.

I did raise a support question with Paypal, but a week has passed and it's gone unanswered, so I'm hoping someone here can tell me what I'm missing in this new version?

Comment: Clear cache and Cookies of your browser.This helped for me.

Comment: I am having the same issue were you able to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce this.  I'm logging into my sandbox accounts just fine.  I'm also able to test things like Express Checkout without any issue.

I know that browser cache and cookies can often be a big issue on the sandbox.  For example, when I first attempted to try this after seeing your post I was getting a Proxy Error when trying to load sandbox.paypal.com.  I closed and re-opened my browser, though, and then everything worked as expected.  Maybe give that a shot.

Comment: I tried a range of browsers as I know my Firefox dies like this and it's the same in all of them. It's very frustrating as it's totally stopped productivity and testing.

Comment: Scrub that. I just cleared out everything in Chrome (Tools > Clear Browsing Data) and wiped everything since the beginning of time and that's got it. Nice catch, thanks Andrew. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew Angell points out - this crazy behaviour was down to the web browser caching. I just cleared out everything in Chrome (Tools > Clear Browsing Data) and wiped everything since the beginning of time and that's got it. Nice catch, thanks Andrew. Appreciated.

The reason every browser I tried did this, is because I've used them all with Paypal - of course - so hence they all do the same thing, leading you to thing the issue is upstream.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your cache and cookie simply by pressing

CTRL + SHIFT + DELETE for WINDOWS

COMMAND + SHIFT + DELETE for MAC

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing doesn't help me with this, **USE CHROME INCOGNITO MODE**(new window) - it works for me :)

Comment: I just tried and incognito mode doesn't work, but clearing the cache works!